# Download excel file generated with Apache Poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I am creating an Excel file with Apache Poi and then downloading it. My problem is that when i try to open the file i get the error:

> The file you are trying to open, 'workbook.xls', is in a different
>   format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is
>   not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do
>   you want to open the file now?

and when i click yes, the downloaded file has strange characters and is not formatted correctly.

If i save the file, instead of download it, it is generated correctly.

Here is my code:

Calling the servlet from angular:

```
NetWorkModel.sendRequestOpiniumServlet("review", metodoPeticion, dataEntrada, "EXCEL", function (response) {
            if (response.Status === 'KO') {
                NotificacionModel.mostrarNotificacion({
                    title: 'Opinium',
                    message: 'Error. No se ha podido exportar a Excel.',
                    size: 'large',//small,large
                    type: 'error',//error,notice,warning
                    duration: '2000'
                });  
            }
            callback();
        });
```

sendRequestOpiniumServlet method in netWorkModel.js:

```
this.sendRequestOpiniumServlet = function (servicioPeticion, metodoPeticion, dataEntrada, tipoPeticion, callback, $files) {

        //Reset de la request y ponemos los valores del ususario
        self.resetValue();
        //Ponemos datos de la peticion
        self.request.Servicio = servicioPeticion;
        self.request.Metodo = metodoPeticion;
        self.request.Entrada = dataEntrada;

        var tipo = "";
        if (tipoPeticion === "JSON") {
            tipo = "";
            self.request.Tipo = tipo;
            self.sendHttpJSON(self.servers.urlOpinium, function (data) {
                callback(data);
            });
        } else if (tipoPeticion === "EXCEL") {
            tipo = "EXCEL";
            self.request.Tipo = tipo;
            self.sendHttpExcel(self.servers.urlOpinium, function (data) {
                callback(data);
            });                
        } else if (tipoPeticion === "CSV") {
            tipo = "CSV";
            self.request.Tipo = tipo;
            var nombreCSV = servicioPeticion;
            self.sendHttpCSV(nombreCSV, self.servers.urlOpinium, function (data) {
                callback(data);
            });
        } else if (tipoPeticion === "IMG") {
            tipo = "IMG";
            self.request.Tipo = tipo;
            self.sendHttpIMG(self.servers.urlOpinium, $files, function (data) {
                callback(data);
            });
        }


    };
```

sendHttpExcel method in netWorkModel.js:

```
 this.sendHttpExcel = function (urlService, callback) {

    $http({
        method: self.servers.method, url: urlService,
        data: JSON.stringify(self.request),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, cfg) {


        if (DescargaExcelModel.createExcel('bookwork', data)) {
            NotificacionModel.mostrarNotificacion({
                title: 'Intranet: Exportación',
                message: 'Fichero exportado correctamente',
                size: 'large', //small,large
                type: 'notice', //error,notice,warning
                duration: '5000'
            });
            callback(true);
        } else {
            NotificacionModel.mostrarNotificacion({
                title: 'Intranet: Exportación',
                message: 'Error en el contenido del fichero',
                size: 'large', //small,large
                type: 'error', //error,notice,warning
                duration: '5000'
            });
            callback(false);
        }


    }).error(function (data, status, headers, cfg) {
        NotificacionModel.mostrarNotificacion({
            title: 'Servidor: ' + urlService,
            message: 'Error en la conexión con el servidor',
            size: 'xlarge', //small,large,xlarge
            type: 'error', //error,notice,warning
            duration: '5000'
        });
        callback(false);

    });         

};
```

createExcel method in DescargaExcelModel.js:

```
angular.module("app.utils").service("DescargaExcelModel", ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
        var self = this;

        this.element = angular.element(  '#link_exportar_file_csv_temp'  );

        this.setElement = function(elem) {
            self.element = elem;
        };


        this.excelToURL = function(content) {
            var blob;
            blob = new Blob(["\ufeff",content], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8',encoding:"UTF-8"});
            return (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
        };

        this.sanitizeExcelName = function(name) {
            if (/^[A-Za-z0-9]+\.xls$/.test(name)) {
                return name;
            }
            if (/^[A-Za-z0-9]+/.test(name)) {
                return name + ".xls";
            } else {
                return "file.xls";
            }
        };
        this.revoke = function(url) {
            return (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(url);
        };
        this.on = function(ele) {
            var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
            e.initMouseEvent("click", false, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            ele.dispatchEvent(e);
        };

        this.createExcel = function(titleFile, dataExcel) {

            var a_href, content, title, url;
            content = dataExcel;
            title = titleFile;


            if (!(content !== null) && !(title !== null)) {
                return false;
            }

            title = self.sanitizeExcelName(title);
            url = self.excelToURL(content);

            self.element.append("<a download=\"" + title + "\" href=\"" + url + "\"></a>");
            a_href = self.element.find('a')[0];

            self.on(a_href);
//            $timeout(function() {
//                self.revoke(url);
//            });
//
            self.element[0].removeChild(a_href);
//            angular.element("#link_exportar_file_csv_temp").removeChild(a_href);
            return true;
        };

    }]);
```

My servlet code:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

                      .
                      .
                      .

                response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=bookwork.xls");
                ExportUtils.convertToWorkBook(request, response, respuesta.getDatos());

                      .
                      .
                      .
}
```

convertToWorkBook method in ExportUtils.java:

```
public static void convertToWorkBook(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, List<Object> data) {


    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();


    // ... Here i create my excel workbook

    workbook.write(out); 
    workbook.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();

}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Usually you get this when a .xlsx file is named .xls or vice-versa, however this seems to be fine here. I would save the file on disk and take a look with a hexdump utility to see if it is a ZIP file (first bytes are the string "PK") or some other unusual content like a HTML error response.

Comment: We had the same problem and fixed it by changeing the contenttype to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`.

Comment: I've tried that  but it does not work for me. If i save the file, in a local path for example, it generates fine but if i try to download it, the file appears with strange characters. You can see the content inside but it is not properly fomatted. I think the problem is when i constrtuct the blob object to donwload the file.blob = new Blob(["\ufeff",content], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8',encoding:"UTF-8"});